# Get distinct values from a column based on distinct values in another column using R

Tags: r

I got this DF

```
    structure(list(patients = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), adm1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), adm2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1), adm3 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), adm4 = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

#>    patients adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
#> 1         1    1    0    0    0
#> 2         1    1    1    0    0
#> 3         1    1    1    1    0
#> 4         2    1    0    1    0
#> 5         2    1    0    0    1
#> 6         2    1    1    0    0
#> 7         2    1    1    0    0
#> 8         3    1    0    0    0
#> 9         3    1    0    0    1
#> 10        3    1    1    0    0
```

and I want to get this table which is basically based distinct values for each patient from the other columns.

```
    structure(list(patients = c(1, 2, 3), adm1 = c(1, 1, 1), adm2 = c(1, 
1, 1), adm3 = c(1, 1, 0), adm4 = c(0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

#>   patients adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
#> 1        1    1    1    1    0
#> 2        2    1    1    1    1
#> 3        3    1    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `aggregate` like below

```
> aggregate(. ~ patients, DF, max)
  patients adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
1        1    1    1    1    0
2        2    1    1    1    1
3        3    1    1    0    1
```

or

```
> aggregate(. ~ patients, DF, FUN = function(x) +(sum(x) > 0))
  patients adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
1        1    1    1    1    0
2        2    1    1    1    1
3        3    1    1    0    1
```

or

```
> aggregate(. ~ patients, DF, FUN = function(x) +(any(x > 0)))
  patients adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
1        1    1    1    1    0
2        2    1    1    1    1
3        3    1    1    0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative with `summarize`. My logic behind using `max` here is that the values are only either 0 or 1, and in case any of them is 1, you'd like a 1 to be added, so it should work.

```
df %>%
    group_by(patients) %>%
    summarize(across(where(is.numeric), max))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   patients  adm1  adm2  adm3  adm4
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1        1     1     1     1     0
#> 2        2     1     1     1     1
#> 3        3     1     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, max), by = patients]
```